# I need to filter the array of object based on the Id

Tags: angular

```
 categories : Question[]; //My array of object
    uniqueids:number[]; // to identify Unique categoryId
    Filteredquestions:Question[]; 

    this.GetAllUniqueCategories(); // To identify the unique categories

      GetAllUniqueCategories()
      {
        for(let i=0;i<this.categories.length;i++)
        {
          let IdToCheck=this.categories[i].questionId;
          for(let k=0;k<=this.uniqueids.length;k++)
          {
            if(this.uniqueids[k]!=IdToCheck)
            {
              this.uniqueids.push(IdToCheck);

            }
          }
        }

      }


       GetAllQuestionsByCategoryId(id:number)
       {
        for(let i=0;i<this.categories.length;i++)
         {
           if(this.categories[i].category.id==id)
           {
              this.Filteredquestions.push(this.categories[i]); 
           }
         }
       }
```

`I have an array of an object (Question[] => properties of question are questionId, questionText, description, categoryId(categoryId values are repeated)).

I need to identify the unique categoryIds first and then need to identify the questions under each unique categories.

I need to display particular questionText under particular categoryId.

I am using angular 7

Comment: questions.filter(x => x.id === id);

Comment: Hi Apporva, welcome to SO, when posting questions try to give the related code snippets, your tried solution & your question in brief also.

Comment: Sure. I have added the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter:

`array.filter(x => x.questionId === value)`